# Get a list of URLs from file and make a numbered array

Tags: arrays, bash, url, sh

Currently I use the following to remove certain URLs from a file:

```
sed -e 's!\http\(s\)\{0,1\}://Goog.le[^[:space:]]*!!g' newfile
```

But because of more and more spam (I get more spam URLs then real URLs) I need to add additional rules.

I want to get a list of URLs from a file `fileA`, place them into an array `arrayB` and  then display the URLs with an `indexB` to the user.

Then I will input the URL `indexB` number for the URLs that shouldn't be removed. With those numbers, sorted from high to low, I walk through the `arrayB`, removing the corresponding index numbers, starting from the highest index. At this point my array contains only the URLs that should be removed from the page `fileA`.

Then I would walk through the `fileA` again and when I find an URL on the page and in the array, I will remove that URL from that `fileA` into `fileB`.

My main concern is now how to compare `arrayB` with `fileA` and remove the URLs in `fileA` which are in the `arrayB` and, when the URL on the page is on one line, remove the line all together.

A caveat, sometimes there is a good and one or more bad URLs on one line and don't know how to handle that.

Comment: The urls in fileA, is a blacklist-candidate list, if I understand correctly (fileA=newfile)? What is the format of the list of URLs? One String=one line=one URL? A short example of source and target would be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My fileA is a html source file which contains http:.... url's inside the page. Some on one line, sometimes two at one line, some hidden inside the text. FileA should be the one to be cleanuped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with you description is, that you explain many details about your approach (starting from the highest index) whithout explanation why. It looks overspecified to me. The order isn't really important.

So here is a different approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
removeUnmatched () {
    key=$1
    shift
    for element
    do
        if [[ $key = $element ]]
        then
            # echo only for debugging
            echo "found $key"
            return
        fi
    done 
    # sed '/$url/d' fileA 
    echo remove $url from fileA 
}

#
# I guess you want to extract urlnames from fileA, so this would be
# urls=($(yourCommandOn fileA))
#
urls=($(< blacklist))
echo "Exclude from blacklist: (Ctrl-D to end)"
collect=$(select url in ${urls[@]}
do
  echo $url
done)
whitelist=($collect)
# echo ${whitelist[@]} 
for url in ${urls[@]}
do
    removeUnmatched $url ${whitelist[@]}
done
```

I use arrays, but don't work with their index. Bashs `select` command works with the index.

I don't know how you get the urls from fileA automatically. Whether and why you like to save the selection for later use (fileB).

Comment: Thank you.Your maybe right about to may details, but ( of course there is a but :-) ) I did have some code running at an other place and want to make it in one script.

Comment: Hmm, I have to be quick with adding a comment, even when I wait 20 seconds I get a warning.  </br>   Interesting about your function. I have to figure out what shift and $element is doing, because I mis **$2** in there for the $withlist array parameter. </br> About my last part of my question, how do I remove the url with the whole line when there is only one blacklisted url on that line?  Thanks again.

Comment: `for element` is the same as `for element in $*`, usable in functions and in scripts as a whole. `shift` discards the first element of $*, so if you have a call `foo 1 2 3`, you have a function with 3 parameters, $1, $2 and $3. If you shift inside foo, $2 gets $1 and $3 gets $2 - you only have 2 parameters left. We call the function with an unknown number of params, but the first one isn't the list, but the element to look up in the list. After saving the first param as $key, shifting removes the old $1 and we end with the list of whitelisted urls as $*.

Comment: Of course I did check it, but you did make it very Very clear. I'm almost there. i would love to give you a vote, but didn't earn enough.